# Angular forEach cannot read Property

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular to get JSON data from url, and with a search term, filter the JSON data and create a new array in order to view filtered JSON data in HTML. 
But when I open the page, console says that "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

This is the code:

search-result.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { JsoncallItem } from "./../jsoncall-item";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-result',
  templateUrl: './search-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-result.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultComponent implements OnInit {

    _postsArray: JsoncallItem[] = [];

    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() showthis: boolean;

    private postsURL ="http://cloudofgoods3/anguler_app_items";

  newArr: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

      getPosts(): void{
        this.http.get<JsoncallItem[]>(this.postsURL).
        subscribe(
            resultArray => {this._postsArray = resultArray;
          this.getResult();
       })
  }
  getResult(){
      this._postsArray.forEach(function(term){
        if(term.title == this.value){
          this.newArr.push(term.title)
        }
      }.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getPosts();
  }
}
```

search-result.compenent.html:

```
<ul *ngIf="showthis">
    <li *ngFor="let item of newArr">
        Say {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is the wrong?

Comment: NOTE: to add element to an array you must use myarray.push(new_element) (not myarray=myarray+ new_element. Anyway why not use filter and map like this.newArray=this._post.filter(f=>f.title==this.value).map(p=>p.title) ?

Comment: I used filter and map but ng build continuously gave errors. Can you give me a filter and map live example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glmwwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your array is **`undefined`** , you are calling the function before setting the **`_postsArray`**. You can fix it with a check or initialize the array,

```
//Initialize as

_postsArray: JsoncallItem[] = [];
```

and

```
if(this._postsArray && this._postsArray.length > 0){
 this._postsArray.forEach(function(term){
        if(term.title == this.value){
          this.newArr = this.newArr + [term.title]
        }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: It worked! But now newArr is not showing any data like empty array, May I push it instead appending?

Comment: yeah you need to push to the array

Comment: I updated the code with push but still not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

initialize the array

```
_postsArray: JsoncallItem[] = [];
```

Call the `setResult` after the subscription instead of onInit.

```
  subscribe(  resultArray =>{
          this._postsArray = resultArray;
          this.setResult();
   })
```

Comment: I updated my code as you mentioned. But still no output at the {{item.title}}